# Using Sikuli to verify data in a table

Tags: python, sikuli

I am using the Sikuli IDE to test an application that returns data in a table. The table is read only and I cannot copy and paste the contents. I can select a row when using the application being built but that's all.
I am currently using the exist() function to verify the data. I am getting good results when I select several rows of table data using Sikuli, and then compare the results.

I have found that using the exists() function can allow small errors to get through and am looking for a more accurate way to verify my search results.

My current code is:

```
If exists(BlockOfTableData.png):

    return '1'

else:

    return '0'
```

Thanks in advance for any help. The help I got on my previous post was excellent.

Comment: Why are you returning strings instead of True and False?

Comment: I think you can call `getScore()` on the result of `exists()` to get how good a match it is (between 0 and 1). So you could test that this is above some higher threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas you can try:

- Copy the data from the table and verify it via code instead of image (more directed towards the general situation and other readers, since you said this won't work)
- Recreate the table using regions - Either static regions or dynamically build them by the corers of the table - and match images within those regions
- Recreate the table using regions and utilize the `text()` feature to read the data off the screen